# Python function keeps returning NameError even with exception handling

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function which works with integers. I have added code for exception handling if strings or floats are entered, however, Python keeps returning either nonsense or `NameError`. At this point I have tried a loop which keeps asking until an integer is entered and a `try` and `except`. Nothing works.

Here's the code:

```
def threes(num):

    """isNotCorrect = True

    while isNotCorrect:
        print(type(num))
        if type(num) is not int:
            print("Sorry, you need to enter a whole number to play Threes.")
        else:
            print('X')
            isNotCorrect = False"""

    try:
        while num > 1:
            if num % 3 == 0:
                num = num/3
            else:
                if ((num + 1) % 3 == 0):
                    num = (num + 1)/3
                else:
                    num = (num - 1)/3
            print(num)
    except NameError:
        print("Invalid number. Please enter a valid number.")
```

Entering a whole number(the intended input) executes the code fine, but everything else leads to a name error like this, where the input is `threes(bob)`. The top part is my attempt at a loop, which also failed and returned the same error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bob' is not defined
```

Comment: It seems that you haven't defined bob variable... Could you please post the entiere code ?

Comment: What did you expect when you  call `threes(bob)` and `bob` is not defined anywhere?

Comment: The exception is raised before the method is executed (`bob` doesn't exist). By not entering the method, the `try` `except` is not being executed. Also, if you want to check the input is a number, the `Except` should check for 
`TypeError`, not `NameError`.

Comment: As Ruud de Jong says, `NameError` is irrelevant to the code you posted. BTW, if you actually _do_ want to catch a non-number being passed to code that needs numbers, you'd normally catch it with `except ValueError`. But it's better to handle that in the code that gets the input data _before_ you pass it to the code which processes that data.

Comment: You may find the info here useful: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NameError: name 'bob' is not defined` means that you try to use a variable named `bob` but you didn't create it.
You have to define what is `bob` like that for exemple :
`bob = 'a simple man'  # bob is a string`
or
`bob = 4  # bob is an integer`

Furthermore, I just want you to know that even if it works, try to avoid using try/except because this is quite slow when you have to enter in the except block.

If you want to check if your variable is an integer I recommend you using :

```
if isinstance(bob, int):
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

Where [isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) is a built-in function.

Comment: Good advice. Exceptions are faster than the equivalent `if...else` code when the exception doesn't actually get raised, but if you expect the exception to be raised more than 5-10% of the time, then the code will run faster if it uses `if...else` code. However, using `isinstance` is better than using `type` for this sort of thing.

Comment: @PM 2Ring Yes, I forgot `isinstance`, I edited.
And about `try...except`, I would add that even if it's less than 5-10% (but not to much neither), I'll prefer `if...else` because it's more constant and predictable which can be useful for multiprocessing purpose (for exemple).

Answer (score 0):

Your bob variable is not defined at all, so you don't reach the try/catch.

Try decalring bob with not a number, `bob = 'test_string'` and retry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `NameError` is being raised from *outside* the function call. When you say:

```
threes(bob)
```

What Python does is:

1. Get the value of `bob`.
2. Call `threes` passing that value as parameter.

`NameError` is raised in step 1., so you don't even get into the function. If you still want to catch it, you should have the `try`/`except` block outside:

```
try:
    threes(bob)
except NameError:
    print("NameError raised.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted simply cannot raise a NameError. The error probably comes from the part where you call you `threes` function. If you just wrote `threes(bob)`, then the NameError will be raised if you did not previously define a variable named `bob`. If you wanted to pass a string, you should call your function like: `threes("bob")`